# Unable to pass interpolated value during transclusion in directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating an email directive as below,

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('email', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,
            template: '<a href="{{email}}">{{email}}</a>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {                
                transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                    scope.email = clone.text();
                });

            }
        };
    });
```

I am using it in the HTML as below,

```
<email>{{emailId}}</email>
```

However, I am unable to pass the interpolated value of `emailId` inside the directive. The output of the directive ends up as,

```
 <a href="{{emailId}}">{{emailId}}</a>
```

How do we pass the actual interpolated value inside the directive?

Plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/AeBfp3VayKihygelKr9C?p=preview

Comment: The directive has a fatal flaw. You can only use it once within a given scope.

Answer (score 0):

To pass a variable to directive scope, simply use an attribute:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('email', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        ̶t̶r̶a̶n̶s̶c̶l̶u̶d̶e̶:̶ ̶t̶r̶u̶e̶,̶
        template: '<a href="{{email}}">{{email}}</a>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {                
            //transclude(scope, function (clone) {
            //    scope.email = clone.text();
            //});
            scope.email = scope.$eval(attrs.addr);
            //OR
            scope.$watch(attrs.addr, function(value) {
                scope.email = value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

## Usage:

```
<̶e̶m̶a̶i̶l̶>̶{̶{̶e̶m̶a̶i̶l̶I̶d̶}̶}̶<̶/̶e̶m̶a̶i̶l̶>̶

<email addr="emailId"></email>
```

There is no need to use transclusion to evaluate an Angular Expression.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS scope.$eval API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval)
- [AngularJS scope.$watch API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: I agree it can be achieved using attributes. But I have to create the simplest possible implementation of email directive. `<email>{{emailId}}</email>` looks easier to use than `<email addr="{{emailId}}"></email>`.

Comment: The implementation doesn't need curly brackets in the attribute. Simply do `<email addr="emailId"></email>`. Both `$eval` and `$watch` evaluate the attribute as an Angular Expression.

Comment: I don't have any issues with curly brackets. I'd just like the implementation in this format `<email>{{emailId}}</email>`

Comment: You are creating a directive that is hard to understand, test, debug, and maintain. What you are doing is an abuse of the transclusion facility. Transclusion is not intended for providing data to directive scope.

Answer (score 0):

You Just have to add Only on directive template ng-transclude on your element
here is the code

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('email', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<a href="{{email}}" ng-transclude>{{email}}</a>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {          
        }
    };
});
```

here is the link
[Plunker http://next.plnkr.co/edit/SY3ih9NwAqz7ZhZg?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/SY3ih9NwAqz7ZhZg?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Comment: I checked your implementation `<a href="{{emailId}}" ng-transclude>{{email}}</a>` and observed that it contains `emailId` which is a variable from the parent controller scope. Since it is a reusable directive, I cannot use any parent scope.

Comment: When I change your implementation to what you have posted above (http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ZMVapMYyJu7KFSI4?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview), the email is not clickable since the `href` hasn't been generated properly.